# Can we inject multiple instances of the same class with different variables?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

Can we inject multiple instances of the same class with different variables?

```
services.TryAddScoped<ISomeClass>(sp =>
{
    return new SomeClass(1);
});

services.TryAddScoped<ISomeClass>(sp =>
{
    return new SomeClass(2);
});
```

And someway pull the needed one into seperate controllers.

Comment: How is the controller meant to know which one to pull? You can pull all of them in using `IEnumerable<>` and then filter to get the one you want, but it's not elegant.

Comment: Thanks @IanMercer. Not sure maybe by a name or something? Work around works but true, not elegant. Hence looking to see any better options.

Comment: If you use Autofac you can use metadata: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html but really what's your use case and why can't you achieve it using interfaces?

Comment: You mean just have multiple interfaces inherit from the same implementation class?
And use the interface I need in the controller?

Comment: Can you explain how SomeClass(1) and SomeClass(2) differ? Could they be different concrete instances with an extra interface? Other options: (ii) inject a `Func<int,SomeClass>` factory? (iii) Register the calling class with a lambda that uses `GetRequiredService<IEnumerable<ISomeClass>>()` and then filters to get the one it needs - but all handled in registration without changing either class?

Comment: SumClass(1) and SumClass(2) only differ by the values set to its attributes and there is no change in behavior. I will check on the below answer and I think thats what you meant?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With `.TryAddScoped` you have only one instance for type, if you use `.AddScoped` you can add multiple instances and receive a IEnumerable in your controller.

If you need named instances, I have created my custom solution:

```
public class NamedService<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Service { get; set; }

    public NamedService(string name, T service)
    {
        Name = name;
        Service = service;
    }
}
```

Extension methods:

```
public static T GetService<T>(this IServiceProvider serviceProvider, string name = null) where T : class
{
    if (name != null)
    {
        var list = serviceProvider.GetServices<NamedService<T>>();
        return list.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == name)?.Service;
    }
    return serviceProvider.GetService<T>();
}

public static IServiceCollection AddScoped<T>(this IServiceCollection services, string name, Func<IServiceProvider, T> factory)
{
    return services.AddScoped(sp => new NamedService<T>(name, factory(sp)));
}
```

Usage:

```
Services.AddScoped("some1", s => new SomeClass(1));
Services.AddScoped("some2", s => new SomeClass(2));
```

Controller:

```
public SomeController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var someInstance = serviceProvider.GetService<ISomeClass>("some1");
}
```